# How to get Default file icon image in flutter just like shown in the first picture?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform, mobile-application

[image: Files with default icon]

[image: Files with Icon defined by me]

Pic 1 Files with default Icons
Pic 2 Files with File Icons defined by me

Answer (score 0):

it's an internal Icon with the device system...

when you save a file or image in a specific root it will be shown as a parent folder.

but if you want to Implement the same Icon in your app Here we are...

`Icon(Icons.folder,color: Colors.blue,)`

Comment: I need the thumbnail image of the file just like shown in the first picture.